# Mixed Effects Model with Nesting - RNAseq differential expression

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I'm new in the RNAseq differential expression analysis and I'd like to know which is the best way to treat my data.

I have RNAseq data collected from iPSCs organized as follows:

I have 2 groups of iPSC (Control-CTL and Treated -T1), each group with 3 individuals. For each individual, we grew 2 clones and each clone was grown in parallel (in 2 different wells) to create replicas (a, b in last column). Data looks like this: 
[image]

I'm interested on the differential gene expression at the Group level (Control vs T1).

First, I would like to know which is the best option to describe the metadata file. Option1 where I name the Individual/Clone by group or Option2 where I name independently the Individual/Clone.

[image]

I have a expression matrix where each row represents the expression of a gene and each column 1sample/replica,i.e, 52.000x12(genesxreplicas) I'd like to calculate the differential expressed genes taking into account the nested data,i.e, each replica comes from 1Clone and each individual has 2 clones.

In R, I am doing this using lme, as follows:

fit <- lme(datExpr~Group, data=metadata, random=~1 | Individual/Clone)

where datExpr has been calculated as follows:
dge.voom = voom(calcNormFactors(DGEList(counts = iPSC_counts),method = 'TMM'), design)
datExpr= dge.voom$E

Comment: I am interested in this question as well. Have you seen this blog post? https://www.nxn.se/valent/2019/2/15/handling-confounded-samples-for-differential-expression-in-scrna-seq-experiments